# SQLite: sqlite3.dll vs System.Data.SQLite.dll?

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

What do I need to use **SQLite with NHibernate** (and **FluentNHibernate**) ?

There is:

**System.Data.SQLite.dll** and **System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll**, (ADO.NET 2.0 provider) available from  http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/

and

**sqlite3.dll** available as binary download
http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

What is the difference? Do I need both, or which one?

The first option installs to C:/...Program Files. Can I copy it from there to my custom SharedLibs folder, or will something reference the files originally installed?

Comment: I think you mixed the file names and the download locations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need `System.Data.SQLite.dll`. You could reference this assembly in your SharedLibs folder and it should be enough. The `sqlite3.dll` is unmanaged code containing the databae engine itself and it is embedded as resource inside the managed `System.Data.SQLite` assembly. Also because of this unmanaged code there are actually two versions of the `System.Data.SQLite` assembly: one for x86 and one for x64, so make sure you reference the correct one for your system.

You could download this assembly from here: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Comment: I second Darin's recommendation. To clarify, `System.Data.SQLite` and `sqlite-dotnet2` are two completely separate projects. I've used `System.Data.SQLite` and been quite happy with it - they have active forums, etc.

Comment: It doesn't look like a separate project -  the http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/ download link goes to the sqlite-dotnet2 sourceforge page.

Comment: I Installed Package System.Data.SQLite.x64 in VS2013 on win7. But, I got error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Devart.Data.SQLite.dll
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: @user3448011 might be worth double-checking exactly what you installed. Because an error occurring in DEVART.Data.SQLite.dll suggests it is a different SQLite driver