# What's the difference between using the Windows Sqlite library and the .NET sqlite library?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sqlite

There are Windows dll's here:

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

There are .NET setups here:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

If I'm using sqlite for an ASP.NET web application, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows .dll's are straight Win32 versions (which, of course, you *can* use from .Net if you wish to).

But if you're using a .Net program (C#, VB.Net or ASP.Net), you're probably better off using the .Net versions.

To elaborate a bit - the .Net version is a fork:

- [System.Data.SQLite About](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

> This is a fork of the popular ADO.NET adapter for SQLite known as
>   System.Data.SQLite. The originator of System.Data.SQLite, Robert
>   Simpson, is aware of this fork, has expressed his approval, and has
>   commit privileges on the new Fossil repository. The SQLite development
>   team intends to maintain System.Data.SQLite moving forward.

You might also be interested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898006/sqlite-sqlite3-dll-vs-system-data-sqlite-dll).

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but is there such a thing as Windows development without .NET anymore, or would you have to use compilers from VS6 and before?

Comment: Yes, of COURSE there's such a thing as "Windows development without .Net"!!!!!!!!!!!