# SQLite3.dll cannot be used in C# application in VS2013 ON WIN 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I need to access SQLite3.dll for my application (x64) C# in VS2013 on win7.

From 
[SQLite: sqlite3.dll vs System.Data.SQLite.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898006/sqlite-sqlite3-dll-vs-system-data-sqlite-dll)

I see that

```
 "The sqlite3.dll is unmanaged code containing the databae engine itself and it is embedded as resource inside the managed System.Data.SQLite assembly. "
```

So, I installed System.Data.SQLite.x64 from package manager:

```
PM> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.x64
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq (≥ 1.0.99.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 (≥ 1.0.99.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 6.0.0.0)'.
'System.Data.SQLite.x64 1.0.99.0' already installed.
My_project already has a reference to 'System.Data.SQLite.x64 1.0.99.0'.
```

I added it as a reference in VS2013. 
But, I got error:

```
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Devart.Data.SQLite.dll

 Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Then, I downloaded Sqlite3.dll (x64) from 
http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

I put  Sqlite3.dll and  Sqlite3.def at bin/Debug and added it as a content file and changed its property of  "copy to output" to "copy always" but I got error.

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in Devart.Data.SQLite.dll

 Additional information: Assembly that contains embedded dotConnect for SQLite license cannot be used with this application: my_app.exe
```

Then, I downloaded Sqlite3.dll (x86) and did the same thing as x64. got the same error:

```
 Additional information: Assembly that contains embedded dotConnect for SQLite license cannot be used with this application: my_app.exe.
```

The link does not help either,
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlite)

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: Well-written question - welcome to SO :)

Comment: The problem is not SQLite. The problem seems to be something called `Devart dotConnect` detecting that you have SQLite but it seems to want some sort of special license.

Comment: What kind of license needed ? How to get it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be referencing this [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/editions.html)
It appears that the assembly contains embedded code from the above link and it requires a licence to work.